# Asynchronous scroll event issue. Pure JS

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, scroll, event-handling, web-worker

I am running JavaScript in a Web Worker with use of AMP script. There are two event listeners - mouseenter and mouseout. Both events work as supposed to, `tooltipElem` appears on mouse enter and disappears on mouse out. Here is my code:

```
    const button = document.querySelector('.tooltip-trigger');
    let tooltipElem;


    button.addEventListener("mouseenter", async function(event) {
    
        let target = event.target;

        let tooltipHtml = target.getAttribute('data-tooltip-text');
        if (!tooltipHtml) return;   

        tooltipElem = document.createElement('span');
        document.body.appendChild(tooltipElem);
        tooltipElem.innerHTML = tooltipHtml;

        /* ... */

    });


    button.addEventListener("mouseout", async function(event) {
    
        if (tooltipElem) {
            tooltipElem.remove();
            tooltipElem = null;
        }
        
    });
```

When scroll event fired `tooltipElem` is removed, but then I am unable to show it again on `button` element click.  To make `mouseenter` work again I have to click at any other point on screen (feels like `mouseout` fixes it).

Doesn't work:

```
    document.addEventListener("scroll", async function(event) {
    
        if (tooltipElem) {
            tooltipElem.remove();
            tooltipElem = null;
        }   
        
    });
```

Tried to use interval, also doesn't work:

```
    var scrolling = false;

    document.addEventListener("scroll", async function() {
        scrolling = true;
    });

    setInterval( function() {
        if (scrolling) {
            scrolling = false;
            if (tooltipElem) {
                tooltipElem.remove();
                tooltipElem = null;
            }
        }
    }, 100 );
```

What can be wrong with my async `scroll`? Maybe event is not finished or memory leaks? No errors...

Here is a video, demonstrating scroll issue in the end (on second block).
https://streamable.com/y53749

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured out that the problem is in `mouseenter` event listener, so replaced it with `click` on touch devices and `mouseenter` on non-touch devices; Didn't managed to detect device in `amp-script` web worker using JS, so used Wordpress `wp_is_mobile()` function;

```
    <?php if ( wp_is_mobile() ) : ?>
    
    // Click (async)
    button.addEventListener("click", addTooltip, false);
    
    <?php else : ?>

    // Mouseover (async)
    button.addEventListener("mouseover", addTooltip, false);
    
    <?php endif; ?>
```